# Local IE rendering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So I have an interesting quirk that isn't making a lot of sense right now.

I am trying to create drop down menus for a website using CSS.

When I open the index.html file locally, it looks fine in Firefox, and it is all messed up in IE.

When I FTP the file to a server, it looks fine in both Firefox and IE.

I would like to be able to see what it is supposed to look like in IE locally, before uploading it to the actual site.

What would cause IE to render incorrectly on the local file, but correctly on a server?

Comment: it must have something to do with the headers the server sends. would help to see some code.

Comment: http://boulderband.org/indextest.html

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, IE9 (and possibly 10, I'm not sure) runs Intranet sites in Compatability Mode, and it defines all locally viewed HTML files as intranet pages. So, when you're accessing local files, you may very well be accessing them roughly as if you're viewing in IE7.

Turning this off has been [covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894082/how-to-prevent-ie9-from-rendering-intranet-sites-in-compatibility-mode).